# Visual Studio 2010 - Can't add a data source through menu

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, datasource

I am developing an ASP.NET 4.0 website through visual studio 2010 and I am new to ASP.NET however I have had experience with VB.NET.

I am trying to add a data source (SQL Server .MDF file) through the data menu as you would when coding a Visual Basic program, but there are no options to do so under the data menu.
Usually I would expect to see a large list of options such as "Add a new data source" but I only have two options "Transact-SQL Editor" and "Schema View".

I have tried adding a database .mdf file manually and connecting to it through code, but Visual Studio will then not create any datasets or data adaptors.

Also under the data sources window, even though I have added a .mdf file and connection string, no data sources appear.

How am I supposed to properly add a data source and create datasets, data adaptors etc?

Answer (score 0):

From the Solution Explorer, right click 'Add ASP.NET folder' then select 'App_Data'. Select 'App_Data' folder, right click then click 'Add New Item'. From there, select 'SQL Server Database'.

<s>You can also add the database into the SQL Server itself (if you have the exising .mdf file already) by clicking View > Server Explorer > Data Connections. Right click then Add connection.</s>

Comment: Thanks for that, i'd been adding the database into the project folder, not the App_Data folder which was the issue i suspect!